# valgrind memory leak while reading a structure from file

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind

I keep getting this valgrind message, but I don't know what to do.

[valgrind message]

```
==27091== HEAP SUMMARY:
==27091==     in use at exit: 96 bytes in 4 blocks
==27091==   total heap usage: 22 allocs, 18 frees, 11,347 bytes allocated
==27091==
==27091== 24 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 2
==27091==    at 0x4847581: calloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==27091==    by 0x1092C6: detailNew (in /home/students/s/smelov.vp/test5/lab5)
==27091==    by 0x10944F: main (in /home/students/s/smelov.vp/test5/lab5)
==27091==
==27091== 72 bytes in 3 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 2
==27091==    at 0x4847581: calloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==27091==    by 0x1092C6: detailNew (in /home/students/s/smelov.vp/test5/lab5)
==27091==    by 0x109534: main (in /home/students/s/smelov.vp/test5/lab5)
==27091==
==27091== LEAK SUMMARY:
==27091==    definitely lost: 96 bytes in 4 blocks
==27091==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==27091==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==27091==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==27091==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

[functions code]

```
detail detailNew(char* idBuf, char* nameBuf, int pcs){
        char *name = calloc(strlen(nameBuf) + 1, sizeof(char));
        char *id = calloc(strlen(idBuf) + 1, sizeof(char));
        strcpy(id, idBuf);
        strcpy(name, nameBuf);
        detail *item = calloc(1, sizeof(detail));
        item->id = id;
        item->name = name;
        item->pcs = pcs;
        free(id);
        free(name);
        return item[0];
}

int main(){
    char idBuf[9];
    char nameBuf[81];
    int pcs;
    FILE *details = fopen("fscanf.txt", "r");
    int inputCheck = 0;
    size_t amount = 0;
    detail *list = calloc(1, sizeof(detail));
    inputCheck = fscanf(details, "%s %s %d", idBuf, nameBuf, &pcs);
    if(inputCheck != 0 && inputCheck != -1){
        list[amount] = detailNew(idBuf, nameBuf, pcs); 
    }
    while(!feof(details)){      
        amount++;
        list = realloc(list, (amount+1) * sizeof(detail));
        inputCheck = fscanf(details, "%s %s %d", idBuf, nameBuf, &pcs);
        if(inputCheck != 0 && inputCheck != -1){
                list[amount] = detailNew(idBuf, nameBuf, pcs); 
        }
    }
    fclose(details);
    printf("lines read: %zu\n", amount);
    list = realloc(list, amount * sizeof(detail));
    ...
    free(list);
    return 0;
}
```

"detail" is a structure

```
typedef struct {
    char *id;
    char *name;
    int pcs;
}detail;
```

here is the "fscanf.txt" file

```
dafhud1t oogabooga 190
ds7fta8s exampletext 69
s8fdgt3q idkwhattowrite 78
dashf79w aaaaaaaahhh 90
```

I was trying somehow to change my code to be able to solve this problem. I think that a problem is that I'm not freeing "item", but I'm not able to do this, because I'm returning it to main function.

Comment: `return item[0];` This returns the content of `*item`. That pointer itself is not longer accessible after your return from this function and you cannot free it afterwards. If you only want to allocate memory for 1 element and only return the content, why do you use dynamic memory at all? Just use a local variable instead.

Comment: If ```fopen``` returned ```NULL```, you would be trying to read/write from ```NULL```.

Comment: Here is why you should never use ["while(!feof(file))"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong)

Comment: And ```realloc```. Neither do you check the return value of ```fscanf()```.

Comment: Valgrind would give you more detail if you ran it with a build of your program that included debug information.

Comment: @Haris I will correct it, my program is not ideal yet

Comment: Is there really a compelling reason that you need to use pointer members in your struct?  This complicates your code.  Use char arrays with reasonable size to accommodate id and name.  Life will be more pleasant.

Comment: @ryyker I need to do this for the university project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here ...

> ```
>         detail *item = calloc(1, sizeof(detail));
> ```

... you allocate space for a `detail`.

Here ...

> ```
>         return item[0];
> ```

... you return *the contents* of that space, by value, without deallocating.  This is the space that is leaked.

Since you are returning the structure by value, an easy way to fix that would be to allocate it automatically instead of dynamically.  You woud then need to use the `.` operator instead of `->` to access the members, or even assign them in an initializer.  Additionally, if you do not have or cannot use `strdup()`, then you can roll your own.

Furthermore, your [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75209974/2402272) (now deleted) was right that it is incorrect to free the `id` and `name` pointers inside `detailNew()`, because you have assigned their (pointer) values to members of the new `detail`.  When you free the space to which `id` and `name` point, you are also freeing the space to which `item->name` and `item-id` point.  You must avoid freeing that space until the program is done using it.

For example:

```
char *strdup(const char *src) {  // only if you don't have it already
    char *dupe = malloc(strlen(src) + 1);
    if (dupe) {
        strcpy(dupe, src);
    }
    return dupe;
}

detail detailNew(char* idBuf, char* nameBuf, int pcs){
        detail item = {
            .id = strdup(idBuf);
            .name = strdup(nameBuf);
            .pcs = pcs;
        };

        return item;
}
```

Comment: So I see, @Gerhardh.  I've updated this answer to acknowledge that, but the key details were already summarized here, so I don't see a need for more than that.